# Openpyxl not showing second graph

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

**EDIT:** Solved, solution in answer below.

I have a graph created with openpyxl that has two y axes sharing a DateAxis. Although the first selection of data is showing on the graph, the second isn't. There's also a strange gray line on the bottom of the graph that wasn't there before. I think it's just a small error I'm missing somewhere, but I can't see where. Especially considering I have my range of cells defined correctly. What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, chart
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference, Series
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta, time
ws2 = wb['sheet2']
dates = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
vBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
qBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_col=3)

c1 = chart.LineChart()
c1.title = "SLA Discharge - 5.5A: V_BAT"
c1.style = 12
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
c1.x_axis = chart.axis.DateAxis()
c1.x_axis.title = "Time"
c1.x_axis.crosses = "min"
c1.x_axis.majorTickMark = "out"
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'd-HH-MM-SS'
c1.add_data(vBat, titles_from_data=True)
c1.set_categories(dates)
c1.y_axis.title = "Battery Voltage"
c1.y_axis.crossAx = 500
c1.y_axis.majorGridlines = None


c2 = chart.LineChart()
c2.x_axis.axId = 500 # same as c1
c2.add_data(qBat, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)
c2.set_categories(dates)
c2.y_axis.axId = 200
c2.y_axis.title = "Qbat Percentage"
c2.y_axis.crossAx = 500

c1.y_axis.crosses = "max"
c1 += c2


s1 = c1.series[0]
s1.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "BE4B48"
s1.graphicalProperties.line.width = 25000 # width in EMUs.
s1.smooth = True # Make the line smooth
s2 = c2.series[0]
s2.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "48BBBE"
s2.graphicalProperties.line.width = 25000 # width in EMUs.
s2.smooth = True # Make the line smooth
ws2.add_chart(c1, "D5")
```

Interestingly enough,

```
vBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
```

is fine. However, doing the same thing to qBat with:

```
qBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=sheet.max_row)
```

"corrupts" the workbook and displays an error message upon opening and doesn't print any chart. Removing `max_row=sheet.max_row` from both lines produces an incorrect DateAxis where there are only two points and they're both the first two values in the `time` column.

Comment: Does this work without using a DateAxis? Combined charts are tricky because they rely on the trick of sharing axes.

Comment: @CharlieClark I tried creating the chart without a DateAxis and had issues with the axes not displaying correctly. I understand that DateAxis doesn't provide much real benefit, but it's been the best shot I've had so far at properly creating the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, in `c2.add_data(qBat, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)`, remove `from_rows=True`.

Then, change `qBat` to:

`qBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=sheet.max_row)`